# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

i am using latest version of android studio 2022.3.1 with gradle 8.3 and gradle plugin version 8.1.1 but getting this error:
**Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.**
how can remove this error

i am trying to find the solution of this error and have alot of research but did not get the answer.
But i am hope full to get answer from this platform

Comment: share to `build.gradle` file, try updating the `jdk` to version 17